# im getting error message "expected ')' in expression list" connected to @IBAction func createaccountButton

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction

```
    @IBAction func createaccountButton(sender: AnyObject) { !Expected ')' in expression list
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("User Created")

    if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil
    {
        self.myaccountButton.alpha = 1.0
    }
    else
    {
        self.myaccountButton.alpha = 0.0
        self.welcomeLabel.text = ""
                }
            }
        }
    )}
}
```

}

i cant figure out where to put ) in said expression please help ive tried everything

Comment: Alex, your error messages seem to have been mixed into your code somehow.  Maybe you could clean that up a little so it's readable?

Comment: Do you get that error when trying to bind from the interface builder or in compile/run time?

Comment: Umm. Post all of your code, as this is not an ample amount of code for us to help you.

Comment: Comment all your code in the file. Then uncomment block by block and watch for the error to appear then fix it.

Answer (score 12):

For those who are having this problem it is because somewhere in your code you are missing a closed parenthesis ). Check the line where you are having the issue or the line before. It is because there is an open parenthesis ( for the argument but no closed parenthesis ) to close it. Make sure your closed parenthesis match the open parenthesis for the argument.

For this specific code it's because you have an open parenthesis with no closed parenthesis to close the argument:

```
(emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
```

You are missing a closed parenthesis above.

You also have a closed parenthesis at the bottom for some reason.

```
        self.welcomeLabel.text = ""
                }
            }
        }
    )} //right here is an obscure closed parenthesis
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing ')' just after your password field!

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!) { (user, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }

  print("User Created")

  if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
     self.myaccountButton.alpha = 1.0
  } else {
     self.myaccountButton.alpha = 0.0
     self.welcomeLabel.text = ""
  }
}
```

with completion, this works fine with me.

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!, completion: { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    print("User Created")

    if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
         self.myaccountButton.alpha = 1.0
     } else {
         self.myaccountButton.alpha = 0.0
         self.welcomeLabel.text = ""
     }
})
```

Comment: No it's not, the parentheses is closed after the completion closure. This kind of error is usually from an upper line in the code.